# non-greedy regex capture groups syntax

Tags: regex, regex-group

given the following text

```
key: foo/bar:v1.2.3
    key: baz/spam:1.2.3 greedy
```

i have tried the following regex:

```regex
^\s*key: (?<ref>.*?):(?<ver>.*)
```

which returns the following groups ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8y3tvj/1)):

- ref: foo/bar, ver: v1.2.3
- ref: baz/spam, ver: 1.2.3 greedy

what is missing from the regex in order to match\group the version (e.g. *1.2.3*) without the preceding text (e.g. *greedy*)?

Comment: Use [`^\s*key: (?<ref>[^:]+):(?<ver>\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/8y3tvj/2)

Comment: You can capture the digits `^\s*key: (?<ref>[^:]+):v?(?<ver>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/bvotwA/1

Comment: @anubhava: if you will convert your comment to an answer, i could accept it :) (if you could explain what is `\S` it will be helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `.*` in your last capture group, it is matching everything till the end of of line in 2nd capture group.

You could restrict matching of your regex to match only non-whitespace characters by using `\S` (which is opposite of `\s` and it matches any character other that whitespaces):

```
^\s*key: (?<ref>[^:]+):(?<ver>\S+)
```

Also note use of a negated character class `[^:]` in 1st capture group to reduce backtracking which matches any character other than `:`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8y3tvj/2)

Answer (score 1):

Another option to match the version number is to match the digits separated by a dot with an optional `v` char.

```
^\s*key: (?<ref>[^:]+):(?<ver>v?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*key:`  Match optional whitespace chars and `key:`
- `(?<ref>[^:]+)` Capture group `ref` match 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:v?` Match `:` and optional `v`
- `(?<ver>` Capture group `ver`

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat the dot and digits
- `)` Close group `ver`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JjoWyM/1)